# How to share PC's internet with Macbook over Bluetooth

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook, bluetooth

I'm trying to share my PC's internet connection with my Macbook via Bluetooth. I've currently got them both paired, which works fine, but it's setting up the internet connection I'm having trouble with.

I've set up bluetooth dial-networking in System Preferences > Network, but every time I try to connect, i get "Timeout sending config requests" or "Modem not responding". Meanwhile, on my PC it says "iMac has successfully connected to DIal-up Networking Service".

Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a heads up, Bluetooth 2.0 Nominal bitrate is 3.0Mbps but the practical bitrate is 2.1Mbps. If both devices are Bluetooth 3+ then you will have a nominal bitrate of 24Mbps. Just wanted to let you know that it would be pretty darn slow in comparison if you had a 50Mbps+ connection.

Comment: Yeah, I know. :/ And I do have a very fast internet connection, but I'm going this route because my wireless card failed, and I'm waiting for the one I ordered to get here. I need a solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use internet connection sharing when bluetooth on your computer is on. That will let to configure internet provisioning for BT PAN compatible at least with SEMC older mobile phones.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I'm a bit confused though - the bluetooth is on, on both of the computers when I'm attempting to connect.

Comment: You need to set up internet connection sharing when one network card is connected to internet and bluetooth PAN is visible enabled among network adapters. Depending on BT software stack you may need to have a PAN clitnt associated, or not. You might need a bluetooth updates from maker or microsoft too.